# Open every window maximized on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, automation

Is there any way (free application preferable, or registry hack) to force Windows XP to open every application (window) maximized?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Brianary](http://brianary.blogspot.com/2009/07/best-registry-hack-ever-maximizeapps.html)

> This registry hack maximizes windows
>   by default when they open!
>
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"MaximizeApps"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm)**

**Automatically maximize** or minimize or normal **all new windows you specify**.

Automatically minimize all new windows you specify to system tray.

Automatically keep all new windows you specify always on top.

Adds several menu items to standard window system menu.

Minimize the current window to system tray.

Apply transparency effect from 0% (fully transparent) to 100% (solid) rate to any program in Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista.

Show window property of application, such as window handle, class name, process id etc.

Auto Refresh Internet explorer at custom intervals.

*Auto Window Manager is freeware.*